# Emulating 'git rebase -i' with reword in GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I'm working on a Python script to reword commit messages before sending out a code review, so that all the commits follow a particular format mandated by our team (e.g. "[UserStoryID] [TaskID] Some description of my commit")

For instance, if I had 3 commits:

```
a1b2c3   Add documentation
d4e5f6   Implement unit tests
c7b8a9   Add feature X
```

I want to rebase/rename to:

```
f9e8d7   US123 - TA456 - Add documentation
c6b5a4   US123 - TA456 - Implement unit tests
e3c2a1   US123 - TA456 - Add feature X
```

With `git rebase -i`, this is easily doable using the `reword` option.  But how can I replicate this functionality in GitPython?  I'm thinking of something along these lines, although it is not valid GitPython:

```
commits = list(repo.iter_commits(max_count=3))
# Reset to the parent commit of the first one we want renamed
repo.head.reference = repo.commit('HEAD~4')
repo.head.reset(index=True, working_tree=True)
# Replay each commit, modifying the message first
for commit in commits[::-1]:
    renamed_commit = commit.clone()
    renamed_commit.message = 'US123 - TA456 - ' + commit.message
    repo.apply(renamed_commit)
```

Comment: I think you mean "using `edit` or `reword` - there is no `rename`"...

Comment: You're absolutely right, I meant `reword`...thanks.